# How to execute Yes,No Dialog boxes in a while loop?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So, I have to give the an option to select Yes or No using JOptionPane dialog box, if the user selects No, the program ends with a message"The program ended!", if the user clicks yes then user needs to select Yes or No again, after 2 or 3 times if the user click No then I have to terminate the program with the message.
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int yesNo;
    String title = "Do you want to continue string comparision?";
    String task = "Strings Comparision?";
    String terminateTask = "End:\nThe program terminates!" + "\nEnd of this program.";

    yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Q: " + title, task, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    while (yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ReQ: " + title, task, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.out.println("Test: End of a single while-loop!");

        }
    if (yesNo == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(terminateTask);
        System.exit(0);
        
    }

    
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand your question by showing the expected result as well as the result you are not satisfied with. Possibly show any log file passages where the error message is contained.  Last but not least, show us your efforts that were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a counter variable and terminate the program if it is a certain number. I modified your code a little bit, so you can have something like this:

```
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Q: " + title, task, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        
        if (yesNo == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION ){
            System.out.println(terminateTask);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if ((counter >= 2)){
            System.out.println("Test: End of a single while-loop!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
         counter++;

}
```